# Loop over two array values at a time

Tags: bash, shell

How can I loop over two array values at a time? I tried using a `for` loop but I could only figure out how to echo one at a time.

```
#!/bin/bash

array=(value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 value6 value7 value8 value9 value10)

for i in ${array[@]}
do
        echo $i
done
```

Is there a way to change the for loop that it will echo two values at a time like below?

```
value1 value2
value3 value4
value5 value6
value7 value8
value9 value10
```

Comment: If there's a second array, you could just do `echo ${array2[$j]}; j=$((j+1))`.

Comment: BTW, remember to quote your variables unless you have a good reason not to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looping over indices will be easier than looping over the elements. You can pull out the two elements by index:

```
for ((i = 0; i < ${#array[@]}; i += 2)); do
    echo "${array[i+0]} ${array[i+1]}"
done
```

Or you could extract [array slices](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) using the syntax `${variable[@]:offset:length}`:

```
for ((i = 0; i < ${#array[@]}; i += 2)); do
    echo "${array[@]:i:2}"
done
```

This would be especially useful if you wanted more than two elements at a time.